# fetch related records between 3 model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have few products in 3 category (for example), and each product has a brand. I want to show brands which related to products in a specific category.

### Models:

--product

--brand

--category

### relations:

category has many products

brand has many products

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you have 3 models with relationships like :

`Brand` Model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

`Product` Model :

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

`Category` Model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

You can use `whereHas` :

```
$brands = Brand::whereHas('products.category', function ($q){
     return $q->where('name', 'category_name');
})->get();
```

Above will give you all brands which has product belonging to category with name as  `category_name`.

If you want to get product and category details then you can eager load :

```
$brands = Brand::whereHas('products.category', function ($q){
    return $q->where('name', 'category_name');
})->with(['products', 'products.category'])->get();
```

Comment: `Brand::->whereHas(...)` should be `Brand::whereHas(...)` and your answer is great except you missed the Brand and Category can `hasManyThrough` each other, which would be really useful.

Comment: Today you're on fire! Every laravel question has your answer :) Keep up.